# How to dynamically add Input field based on multiple selected values in dropdown in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to add input field based multiple selected dropdown values, a corresponding input field should be displayed based on the selection.

i.e if I add father, and mother from the dropdown field the corresponding both Father Age input field and mother Age input field should be displayed.

```
 **<div class="col-2">
                      <label for="members">Members to be Incured</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4">
                        <ngx-select-dropdown #t [config]="config" [options]="dropdownOptions" (change)="checkFamily($event)" formCoxntrolName="membersIncur" 
                        [multiple]="true" ></ngx-select-dropdown>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="col-2">
                      <label for="age">Your Age<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-2">
                      <input type="number" formControlName="age"> 
                      <div *ngIf="submitted && cf.age.errors">
                            <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="cf.age.errors.required">
                             Age is required
                            </div>
                          </div>
                  </div>



                </div>
                <div class="form-row">

                  <div class="col-2">
                        <label for="age">Father Age<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <input type="number" formControlName="fatherAge">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && cf.fatherAge.errors">
                                <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="cf.fatherAge.errors.required">
                                Father Age is required
                                </div>
                              </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-2" >
                              <label for="age">Mother Age<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-2" >
                              <input type="number" formControlName="motherAge">
                              <div *ngIf="submitted && cf.motherAge.errors">
                                    <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="cf.motherAge.errors.required">
                                     Mother Age is required
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the function you created in change event:

```
checkFamily(evt: any) {
// here evt will be the array of the selected options with complete json format
// you can check for changes here itself
}
```

For more information plz visit:
[here](https://manishjanky.github.io/ngx-select-dropdown/) 
OR
[this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-select-dropdown)

Comment: I am getting evt as an array, i.e ['father', 'mother'] , I want to display the input field of each seperately in html how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with ngIf, you can add or remove the div node based on the value of dropdown, you can check if value in membersIncur is father or not, something like this:-

```
 <div *ngIf="cf.membersIncur.value=='fathersVal'" class="form-row"><!--validate the value of dropdown here-->
              <div class="col-2">
                <label for="age">Father Age<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-2">
                <input type="number" formControlName="fatherAge">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && cf.fatherAge.errors">
                  <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="cf.fatherAge.errors.required">
                    Father Age is required
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
```